# Incorrect number of daily active users on Android in BigQuery

Tags: android, sql, firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

In BigQuery, I use the following query to get the number of daily active users:

`

```
#legacySQL
SELECT
  user_dim.app_info.app_platform as appPlatform,
  event_dim.date as eventDate,
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id) as daily_active_users
FROM
  TABLE_QUERY([table_name], 'table_id CONTAINS "app_events_"'),
  TABLE_QUERY([table_name], 'table_id CONTAINS "app_events_"')
GROUP BY
  appPlatform, eventDate
ORDER BY
  appPlatform, eventDate
```

`

The result of this query for a concrete date is [534 users for Android and 142 users for IOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDBYn.jpg).

But Firebase shows that there were only 209 active Android users this day.
And this number is correct, because I can compare it with data from Appsee.
As for IOS, Firebase returns exactly the same number as my query in BigQuery.

**What is wrong in my query and how can I solve this issue?**

I have tried to write the query in standard SQL, as well:
`

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  event.date as date,
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id) AS daily_visitors
FROM `table.table.app_events_*`
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(event_dim) AS event
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date DESC
```

`
But the result of this query is absolutely the same as the one mentioned earlier: 534 daily users instead of 209 for Android, correct number for IOS.

**So, I think that the problem is in my misunderstanding of inner FB/BQ mechanisms.**

**Please, help me to figure out the root of the issue.**

Comment: Part of the problem is that `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` is only an approximation when using legacy SQL.

Comment: you could also try using `EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT` instead of the `COUNT(DISTINCT)` as Elliott pointed out. Still, is there any reason for not using the standard version of BQ?

Comment: COUNT(DISTINCT) and EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT give the same results, in my case.

What do you mean saying "standard version of BQ"? Standard SQL?

And I have exactly the same number of users for IOS as Firebase shows me, when I use COUNT(DISTINCT) or EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT. But for Android users the result is more than 2 times higher than the one in FB.

Answer (score 0):

Further query returns correct number of daily active users for both platforms:

```
#legacySQL
SELECT
  event_dim.date as eventDate,
  CASE WHEN user_dim.app_info.app_platform = 'IOS' AND EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id) !=0 THEN INTEGER(EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id))
  ELSE 0
  END as IOS_dau,

  CASE WHEN user_dim.app_info.app_platform = 'ANDROID' AND EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id) !=0 THEN INTEGER(EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id))
  ELSE 0
  END as ANDROID_dau,  

FROM
  TABLE_QUERY([table:table_IOS], 'table_id CONTAINS "app_events_"'),
  TABLE_QUERY([table:table_ANDROID], 'table_id CONTAINS "app_events_"')
WHERE event_dim.name = 'user_engagement'
GROUP BY 1, user_dim.app_info.app_platform
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Comment: My first query gave me incorrect result, because I did not take into account that one user can open app a few times.